# Why doesn't ASP.NET (3.5) always load an external javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, firefox

I have an external JavaScript in an asp.net 3.5 project.
While writing different functions, sometimes the JavaScript is loaded into FF and sometimes it is not (based on FireBug) and the JavaScript does not run.
Even if there is an error in the JS it should still load or be visible to the browser, right?

What is the logic behind when it is loaded and when it doesn't load (or is accessible to the browser?)

**EDIT**

Master Page loads JS from a script directory in project:

```
<head runat="server">

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
     <!-- Google JavaScript for gauges -->
       <script src='http://www.google.com/jsapi' type='text/javascript' ></script>   
    <!-- Style Sheet -->
       <link href="../Styles/EliteCircle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />    
    <!-- My local JavaScript File -->
       <script src="Scripts/JScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
</head>
```

JScript.js

```
//Load google api
 google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['gauge']});
 google.setOnLoadCallback(update);




 function update(x) {

 var test = parseInt(x.value);    

 var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
 data.addColumn('string', 'Label');
 data.addColumn('number', 'Value');
 data.addRows(3);
 data.setValue(0, 0, 'Memory');
 data.setValue(0, 1, 0);
 data.setValue(1, 0, 'CPU');
 data.setValue(1, 1, 55);
 data.setValue(2, 0, 'Network');
 data.setValue(2, 1, 68);

 var chart = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
 var options = { width: 400, height: 120, redFrom: 90, redTo: 100,
 yellowFrom: 75, yellowTo: 90, minorTicks: 5
 };

 //smooth transition to new value, need to implement "from" value.
 setTimeout(function() { data.setValue(0, 1, test); chart.draw(data, options); }, 0);


 chart.draw(data, options);


 }
```

Comment: Without seeing your markup and at least one example of such a function, it is impossible to answer your question.

Comment: Also, what exactly do you mean by "load".  Downloaded from the server, eg. fetched via a HTTP GET?  Read into the browser, ie. from the cache or network?  Or the DOM "load" event?  HTML "Onload"?

Comment: Not being read by the browser. For example, in FireBug it shows different JavaScript files that are "visible" to the browser, of the current page. Sometimes it is there and it's functionality works, sometimes it does not appear in the list and there is no functionality. It seems so random, have yet to determine the cause. Right now the browser seems to be "reading" it OK....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it runs, even when it's not loaded, that's most probably because a cached version is used.

Comment: +1 - you could try appending a random number to the Javascript file, to force loading the file: Scripts/JScript.js?r=123456879

Comment: +1 - I don't know how many times this has caught me. It's shameful, really.